# Return each instance of a regex

Tags: regex, string, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I've extensively googled and everyone keeps telling me how to return the LINE that the regex matches...

go lets say that i have a line like this in a text file:

```
<a href=http://google.com> Google </a>
```

I want to be able to return ONLY what occurs between > and < ("Google"). The problem is that I could have a file with thousands of lines like that and I only want to have sed/awk return the EXACT string that matches the regex.

I figured it would be something along the lines of :

```
sed 's/>.*</p'
```

but obviously that wont work...

Its killing me because im sure its probably very simple but i just cant find the right sed line. can sed just not do it?

So I just want it to search through a file, match the regex i give it, and return the exact match (not the line)

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

#### With `sed

```
sed -n 's/^.*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/p'
```

Comment: @glenn: then I would say use a real XML/HTML parser. If it gets more difficult than a simple regex then time to abandon the simpler tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep, the `-o` option does what you want.

```
echo '<a href=http://google.com> Google </a><span>foo</span>' | 
grep -oP '(?<=>).*?(?=<)'
```

returns

```
 Google 
foo
```

This assumes your html tags and their enclosed data are on one line. This would not match

```
<a href=...>
blah
</a>
```